# {% redirect "{{ entry.url }}" %} doesn't work

Tags: templating, redirect

I've set up a structure channel that has entries at /services/slug however I want the /services template to redirect to the first entry in the services structure.

What I have now is:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('services').limit(1) %}
  {% redirect '{{ entry.url }}' %}
{% endfor %}
```

However when visiting /services this redirects to a 404 page with url of `/%7B%7B%20entry.url%20%7D%7D/`

I also tried {% redirect "services/{{ entry.slug }}" %} but that didn't work either.

Is it possible to set up a redirect in the way that I am trying to do here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not use the {{ }} inside other brackets you also should not use ' ' unless it is a specific string you want interpreted. Try instead:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('services').limit(1) %}
     {% redirect entry.url %}
{% endfor %}
```

And you should be good to go